# how to import sklearn.impute on jupyter NoteBook?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

have problem importing impute module from sklearn in jupyter :

> from sklearn.impute import SimpleImpute

I've tried every solution till now,
installing the latest version of both sklearn(0.23.1) and jupyter(6.0.3) notebook
but still have the same error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.impute'

I've already tried the same codes on IDLE and there's no problem
the problem is on jupyter

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below command in jupyter-notebook and verify if `scikit-learn` of version `0.23` is in the list. If it is not in the list, then it means your IDLE and jupyter-notebook are using different python installations. (since it is working in IDLE)

```
!pip list
```

If it is missing in the list, then install it directly from jupyter-notebook using

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I checked the version on the Jupyter-notebook and that wasn't changed due to the different python installations so I've update it on jupyter